# creation of an object in another class(without inheritance)

Tags: c++

Hi everybody=) the problem: Compilier can't executed a constructor of class oper because there is no default constructors in class person.
text of error:
'person' : no appropriate default constructor available

the question is: How I can solve this problem without creating default constructors and without inheritance.
here is the code of class person:

```
  class person:public gsm
{
public:
    string name,tel;
    int tax;
public:
    person(string m);
    person(string m,string t,string n,int a);
    void input(string n, string t, int tx);
    void output();
    person& operator=(person& a);
    bool operator==(person& a);
    bool operator!=(person& a);
};
```

and this is class operator:

```
class oper
{
private:
    person b[10];
    int mid_tax1,mid_tax2;
public:
    oper();
    void set_t1(int tax);
    void set_t2(int tax);
    void count();
    void add_person(person a,int i);
    void out();
};
```

constructor of class oper:

```
oper::oper()
{
    this->mid_tax1=0;
    this->mid_tax2=0;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        b[i].tel="";
        b[i].name="";
        b[i].tax=0;
    }
}
```

Comment: add a default ctor for person as compiler asks. if you define any ctor - compiler does not generate a default ctor

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now it works. with default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

class oper contains 10 instances of person. To build oper you have to build the 10 instances.

When you are in the constructor of oper::oper you are after the class and its contents were constructed. Since there is no default constructor for person there is no way for the compiler to build oper.

Why aren't you allowed to use a default constructor?

Why are you creating a fixed array of 10 people and then support a function called add_person? Is the number of people fixed or dynamic?

If you are using C++03 / C++11 you can use initializer lists to pass the values to the Ctor of person during construction. But it will not be a pretty piece of code.

```
oper::oper()
  : b({""},{""} .... ), mid_tax1(0), mid_tax2(0) 
{
  ...
}
```

The correct solution is either adding a default constructor or moving away from a fixed array of 10 persons to a dynamic container of N persons

Comment: Thanks a lot)) 
fortunately i have a list of member function and there haven't default constructor.

Comment: I don't understand the comment..

if you change the ctor definition of person to:
   `person(string m="");`
you get your default constructor

Comment: Also if it is very likely that oper() should support a dynamic number of `person`s and not a fixed 10 `person`s for every oper().

Comment: I have another class, and person inheritanced first class(not oper)

Comment: and i can't use default cinstructor because task is to do it without default constructor.

Answer (score 1):

use std::list instead of the array.